# Use Kafka in AWS EBS microservice docker environment to avoid losing user requests and handle more concurrent hits

Tags: scala, docker, apache-kafka, akka, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Currently, I am using AWS EBS microservice docker environment to deploy the micro-services which are written in Scala and Akka. If anyone of the microservice docker is crashed and restarted again. In this case, we will lose the user requests and service will not return any response for those cases. My current architecture can handle up to 1000 concurrent requests without any issues. To avoid this issues, I am planning to store and retrieve all the requests and responses using Kafka.

So I want to use Kafka to manage the request and responses of all my web services and include a separate service or web socket to process all the requests and store the responses again to Kafka. In this case, if my core process docker crashed or restarted. It won't lose any request and responses at any point in time. It will again start to read the requests from Kafka and process it.

All the web services will store the request in relevant topic in Kafka and get the response from relevant response topic and return back to an API response. I have found the following library to use Kafka in Scala web services.

https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka/

[image]

Please check the attached architecture diagram which I am going to use it to efficiently handle a large number of concurrent requests from client apps. Is it a good approach to proceed? Do I need to changes anything in my architecture?

I have created this architecture after done more research about Kafka and microservice dockers. Please let me know if anything wrong with this architecture.

Comment: In general, these kind of questions are off-topic in SO. Can you elaborate what is the use of Kafka in this architecture? Why do you need it at all?

Comment: I want to store all the requests coming from client apps to kafka. All the APIs will store the requests and core process will take the request and process it then store it in a separate topic. API will get this response using the relevant correlation id and return back the response to client apps. I want to use Kafka to avoid data loss and handle a large number of concurrent requests.

Comment: If core process docker container crashes still I believe there might be different instances which can take request in AWS environment which offers high availability and scalability. I think there is no need of Kafka here in this scenario. According to my understanding its better to use Kafka and complicate the system if there is communication with external services. Please reply if I am wrong. I would like to know if I am missing something. @Yuval

Answer (score 0):

This is Kafka's bread and butter so I don't think you're going to run into any architectural issues with this. Just be aware that there is a pretty large amount of operational overhead with Kafka. A good resource for getting started is Kafka: The Definitive Guide written by Confluent (https://www.confluent.io/wp-content/uploads/confluent-kafka-definitive-guide-complete.pdf) . It goes into detail on a lot of common operational issues that they don't mention in the documentation.